# Обработка двух событий в одном и том же контейнере Vue

Tags: html, vue.js

Как обрабатывать наведение на ссылки, которые находятся в одном контейнере.

При наведении на первую должен появиться блок `first`, на вторую `second`, а при отведении - исчезнуть.

```
<div class="container">
    <a id="link-1"> Первая</a>
    <div class="first"></div>
    <a id="link-2"> Вторая</a>
    <div class="second"></div>
</div>

<script>
  var container = new Vue({
      el: '.container',
     /*что дальше  ..... */
   })
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как например [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/7jmjmjp7q1):

Создаем список из кнопок и контента. При наведении, проверяем для какого пункта (`index`) показывать контент и плавно с помощью `transition` отображаем соответствующий контент:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <ul>
      <li
        :key="index"
        v-for="(m, index) in items"
        :class="{ active: show === index }"
        @mouseover="show = index;"
        @mouseout="show = false;"
      >
        {{ m.text }}
        <transition name="fade">
          <div v-if="show === index">{{ m.body }}</div>
        </transition>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

В js из данных указываем `show: false`, изначально контент скрываем  + сам список в котором имя кнопки `text` и содержимое контента `body`:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      show: false,
      items: [
        { text: "Первая", body: "First content" },
        { text: "Вторая", body: "Second Content" }
      ]
    };
  }
};
</script>
```